# JavaScript - append a new array to object and push values simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping through an array of objects and inside that, I have to append a new array to each object and also push some value in that new array as well. Below is the code:

```
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    arr[i]['newArray'].push(i)
}
```

Generally, I had done this for appending new properties to object via `obj['newProperty']` but never tried for arrays, but this doesn't work. Obviously this isn't right then, but how do I get this working. The objective is to create a new array, append to object and store value in that array, all in one go.

Comment: please add the array, you are talking about.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're looking for. Can you show an example of your structure before and after this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The objective is to create a new array, append to object and store value in that array, all at one go.

I think you mean this:

```
arr[i]['newArray'] = [i];
```

which can also be written as

```
arr[i].newArray = [i];
```

That creates a new array containing the value from `i` using an array initializer (`[i]`), and assigns that array as the value of the property `newArray` on the object `arr[i]`.

Comment: if property already defined and contains elements....  `arr[i]['newArray'] = arr[i]['newArray'] || []; arr[i]['newArray'].push(i);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: But technically isn't "all at one go." :-) (Not that that should usually be a goal.)

Comment: Awesome, just a small miss. So, the i was to be modified. Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    // Check if the array don't exists
    if (!arr[i]['newArray']) {
        // add a new array
        arr[i]['newArray'] = [];
    }

    // otherwise push the value in both the case
    arr[i]['newArray'].push(i)
}
```

**Edit**: For all in one go:

```
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    arr[i]['newArray'] = [i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you went wrong is, u did not create a new array each time. You have to create a new array and then push values into it.

```
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
    //checking and creating new array.
    newArr = arr[i]['newArray'] || (arr[i]['newArray'] = []);
    newArr.push(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm holding the reference of the newly created array so that i can push values/objects in it latter.